# Video Frame Rotation Using OpenGL

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-camera, video-processing

I am working on a rotation of video frames to any degree between 0 to 360   for that I used OpenGL to rotate frames and get rotate the video to any degrees but the problem is after saving the video its view is stretched like this 45 degrees link [rotated video sample frame image with stretch corner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CkALE.png)  but I want this result [rotated video frame image with a perfect 45 degrees](https://i.stack.imgur.com/R3kAb.png)  code sample that I'm using please check

```
import android.opengl.Matrix; 
private float[] MVPMatrix = new float[16];
Matrix.setRotateM(MVPMatrix, 0, 45, 0, 0, -1.0f);
```

please help me to find out the perfect solution, Any help will be appreciated

Comment: may this link helps you [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33773770/use-rotatem-of-matrix-to-rotate-matrix-from-surfacetexture-but-corrupt-the-vid)

Comment: thanks but not helpful for me please suggest something else

Answer (score 0):

to apply rotation/scale/translation to MVPMatrix you should setup projection matrix first (width, height - size of result video)

```
GLES20.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);
float ratio = (float) width / height;
Matrix.orthoM(mMVPMatrix, 0, -ratio, ratio, -1, 1, -1, 1);
```

Then, you need to apply transformations to model matrix

```
Matrix.translateM(mTranslateMatrix, 0, dx, dy, 0);
mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mTranslateMatrix, 0);

Matrix.setRotateM(mRotationMatrix, 0, rotation, 0, 0, -1.0f);
mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mRotationMatrix, 0);

Matrix.scaleM(mScaleMatrix, 0, scaleX, scaleY, 1);
mTempMatrix = mModelMatrix.clone();
Matrix.multiplyMM(mModelMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mScaleMatrix, 0);
```

And finally apply model matrix to MVPMatrix

```
mTempMatrix = mMVPMatrix.clone();
Matrix.multiplyMM(mMVPMatrix, 0, mTempMatrix, 0, mModelMatrix, 0);
```