# Rotate the matrix (frames) of a video in a GlSurfaceView.Renderer implementation

Tags: android, video, gpu, gpuimage, egl

I am using [GPUVideo-android](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android) library to apply filters to my ExoPlayer backed video. I use filters like Brightness, Contrast, Pixelation etc.

*See footnotes for context or background information.*

When I use [GPUPlayerView](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/blob/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/player/GPUPlayerView.java) from that library, the played/rendered video is not rotated according to video's metadata.

This is because GPUPlayerView uses a [GPUPlayerRenderer](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/blob/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/player/GPUPlayerRenderer.java) to render the frames onto a `SurfaceView`. So, this renderer has no way to check the orientation of video.

If I created a method like `renderer.setRotation(Int)`, what will be the body of this method? I have no prior experience with OpenGl/EGL stuff. I want to learn more about it (to continue future development), but I don't have time at present.

I have tried to apply solution from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34668611/3682535) which tells me to add:

```
Matrix.rotateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, 90, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.translateM(mTmpMatrix, 0, 0, -1, 0);
```

I added above code before [line number 154](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/blob/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/player/GPUPlayerRenderer.java#L154), where I replaced `mTmpMatrix` with `MVPMatrix` in `onDrawFrame()`. But, I wasn't successful. I tried to write the snippet below [line number 156](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/blob/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/player/GPUPlayerRenderer.java#L156) too.

I have, also, tried to create a `tempMatrix` of `float[16]`. And then, do this in `onDrawFrame()`:

```
GLES20.glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

tempMatrix = MVMMatrix.clone();

Matrix.rotateM(tempMatrix, 0, 90, 0, 0, 1);
Matrix.translateM(tempMatrix, 0, 0, -1, 0);

Matrix.multiplyMM(tempMatrix, 0, VMatrix, 0, MMatrix, 0);
Matrix.multiplyMM(tempMatrix, 0, ProjMatrix, 0, MVPMatrix, 0);

previewFilter.draw(texName, tempMatrix, STMatrix, aspectRatio);
```

But, I wasn't successful.

So, how can I write a method like `renderer.setRotation(Int)`?

---

#### EDIT 1:

I have, also, found [some relevant code](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage/blob/master/framework/Source/iOS/GPUImageView.m#L386) in iOS version of similar library, but it doesn't help me.

#### EDIT 2:

If I add `Matrix.rotateM(MMatrix, 0, 90, 0, 0, 1);` at the end of [line number 134](https://github.com/MasayukiSuda/GPUVideo-android/blob/master/gpuv/src/main/java/com/daasuu/gpuv/player/GPUPlayerRenderer.java#L134), rendering frame is rotated. But, it becomes square. So, if video was 720x1280, it becomes 720x720 leaving black space above and below the frames after I add this line.

---

Footnotes / Context:

When I record a video from my device, it is saved with a rotation orientation of 90 degrees. I verified this by using `MediaMetadataRetriever`

```
val extractedRotation = retriever.extractMetadata(
    MediaMetadataRetriever.METADATA_KEY_VIDEO_ROTATION
).toIntOrNull()
```

If the rotation is 90 or 270, I swap the width and height so that my layout shows correct aspect ratio of video.

```
val (correctedWidth, correctedHeight) = when (extractedRotation) {
    90, 270 -> arrayOf(extractedHeight, extractedWidth)
    else -> arrayOf(extractedWidth, extractedHeight)
}
```

If the video resolution is 1280x720 with a rotation of 90, corrected resolution becomes 720x1280.

When I play this video in ExoPlayer's `PlayerView`, video is played correctly. I think ExoPlayer respects video's orientation metadata.

Comment: Do you get answer of your question then please help me. I have same issue of rotation.

Comment: I didn't get an answer to my question. Although if I learned more about graphics, I could've done this. But, I never had enough time. 

I was, also, using ffmpeg lib in my app, so I resorted back to properly rotating video with ffmpeg before submitting it to exoplayer. When a video with rotation-flags is passed to ffmpeg, it rotates the video correctly and clears rotation-flags on output. Takes 10~12sec for a video duration of 10sec.

Comment: @KinalMer If you do find a solution, please add it as an answer here.

Comment: @runpinderjeet Sure.